# BigQuery getting Correlated subqueries error - to get previous event

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I have 2 BigQuery tables:

1- Trips

```
car     start                   end    
---------------------------------------------------
1       2019-03-13T17:07:00     2019-03-13T17:17:00
2       2019-03-13T17:07:00     2019-03-13T17:22:00
3       2019-03-13T17:07:00     2019-03-13T17:34:00
4       2019-03-13T17:07:00     2019-03-13T17:12:00
```

2- Tracking

```
car     created_at              status  
--------------------------------------
1       2019-03-13T17:01:00     1
1       2019-03-13T17:02:00     1
1       2019-03-13T17:03:00     1
1       2019-03-13T17:04:00     1
1       2019-03-13T17:05:00     2
1       2019-03-13T17:06:00     2
1       2019-03-13T17:18:00     3
1       2019-03-13T17:19:00     3
1       2019-03-13T17:20:00     3
1       2019-03-13T17:21:00     3
1       2019-03-13T17:22:00     3
```

The tracking table contains the status of a car until it was on a trip. My objective is to get the status of a car on the previous moment of a trip.

My approach so far was:

```
select *,
(select status created_at from tracking
  where car = tracking.car
  AND start > created_at
  order by created_at desc
  limit 1
) as previous_status
from trips
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.
```

Any clue on how to rewrite the query for BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the previous event use `LAG() OVER()` as in:

```
SELECT actor.login
  , type
  , LAG(type, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY actor.login ORDER BY created_at) prev_type
FROM `githubarchive.day.20190313` 
WHERE actor.login IN ('00aquir', '0123hoang')
LIMIT 100
```

[image]